# .NET Connection to dBase .dbf file

Tags: .net, winforms, dbase

I'm trying to read a dBase III .dbf file using .NET and Winforms and nothing I've tried seem to work. I tried four different connection methods and every one of them hangs on `Open` method. No exceptions, no timeouts, no event messages, nothing. The form just sits there. Any ideas about what could be wrong?

Here's the methods I've tried. The .dbf file is at d:\db:

```
private void read1()
        {
            string c = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\\db\\;Extended Properties=dBASE III";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(c);
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("ok");
            conn.Close();

        }

        private void read2()
        {
            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection oConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
            oConn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=D:\db;Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";
            oConn.Open();
            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
            oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM D:\db\Poi.dbf";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
            MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
            oConn.Close();
        }

        private void read3()
        {
            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection oConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
            oConn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=d:\db;";
            oConn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("ok");
            oConn.Close();
        }

        private void read4()
        {
            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection oConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
            oConn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};datasource=d:\db\";
            oConn.Open();
            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
            oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM D:\db\Poi.dbf";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
            MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
            oConn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I wanna to help, but where I find a DBF file this days? =)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + 
    @"Data Source=C:\full-path-without-filename;" + 
    @"Extended Properties=dBASE III;"))
using (OleDbCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
{
    cn.Open();
    cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM fox_samp"; // fox_samp is your filename
    using (OleDbDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

I just ran this without errors. And this site can be very useful: [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work either. It hangs on Open(). I think something is wrong with the file or my computer..

Comment: I suggest you to build a console application and to make a very simple example, like above; or you could also to use OdbcConnection and related classes

Answer (score 1):

Simply it cannot work since 64 bit systems no more support odbc dbf driver for 64 bit nor jet exists anymore..